# What is the format of Mediawiki's AdminSettings.php

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to run dumpBackup.php and I get

```
php dumpBackup.php  --current
DB connection error: Unknown error
```

My understanding is I need to copy the file AdminSettings.sample to .php.
But I don't seem to have such a file.  What is the format of it. Probably looking in the wrong place but all references refer to the sample file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find AdminSettings.sample in the root of your MediaWiki install - in the same directory as LocalSettings.php, one directory up from the "maintenance" directory.

Details:

- http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/AdminSettings.sample?view=markup
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:AdminSettings.php